# Searialing enums as int value using @JsonProperty

Tags: java, json, enums, jackson

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public enum ReviewersRating {
    @JsonProperty(0)_0,_1, _2, _3, _4, _5;  
}
```

I have a enum that need to be converted to their int values respectively. I have been sucessfuly if the value is of `String` type but how do I do so for other data type like `int`?

As suggested by one of the comments, I tried

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public enum ReviewersRating {
    _0(0),_1(1), _2(2), _3(3), _4(4), _5(5);

    private int rating;
    private ReviewersRating(final int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public int toInt()
    {
        return rating;
    }
}
```

Result is still not printing in int type. I get this in JSON `"ReviewersRating": "_0",`

Comment: may be assign an int value for each enum value and add the json annotation on the getter method of this int value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@JsonValue` on the getter method did the trick

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

public enum ReviewersRating {
    _0(0),_1(1), _2(2), _3(3), _4(4), _5(5);

    private final int rating;
    private ReviewersRating(final int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public int toInt()
    {
        return this.rating;
    }
}
```